# How can I route all my server's ports from my openvpn server to my local server?

Tags: routes, port, portforwarding, openvpn

How can I route all my server's ports from my openvpn server to my local server?

Hello, I currently have a server at home but I'd like to be able to access it from the outside and have my ports open so that my sites are public. However, I don't have access to my router's panel and so I'd like to set up an OPENVPN server to route the ports on it.

I've already installed an openvpn server on microsoft azure and I can connect to it and access the internet via vpn, but I don't know how to route the ports on it so that they can be accessed from everywhere.

example: publicip:8080 → vpntunnel → localserver:8080

PS: the ports on my Azure server are already open.

Thanks a lot!

[image: schema]